# Absolute positioning image to the right of dynamic width select

Tags: css, css-position

I have a `select` dropdown that will be of dynamic width.  I want to introduce some space between this dropdown and the image to the right, but have not been able to do so using CSS.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xqruY/1/

Comment: Please post your code here. Also, why is the image absolutely positioned, and have you tried `select {
    margin-right:20px;
}`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W8qcN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the positions and top and... make the css clean and only use what you need.

```
#select {
    float:left;
}
#img{
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W8qcN/

Answer (score 1):

Just add margin-left: (number)px in the css of the image.

e.g.

```
margin-left: 50px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xqruY/2/